# How do you indent a bulleted list in a README file using GitHub flavored markdown?

Tags: markup, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I know I can use asterisks to do something like this:

- list item1
- list item2

but I was expecting something like `**` to indent it one further. Is it possible?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Sub Lists in GFM(github-flavored-markdown) are done the ways represented below.

```
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
  - Sub Item 1
  - Sub Item 2
   
#^ two spaces
```

OR

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
  * Sub Item A
  * Sub Item B
```

Refer to this [Cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Comment: Both of these worked for me, but I needed four spaces to indent the 2nd level bullets

Comment: can this be done for numbered lists instead of bullets?

Comment: 2-5 spaces worked for me, but you have to add a space and at least a character after the bullet point, like so: " * word"

Comment: Also works for numbered lists

Comment: Also work for check lists

Comment: does this work when a list has breaks in between?